# reach out $this->basePath() in js file

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I need to show some products images generated from database on a page. I use ZF2.

I have database table with `src` column (data in this column is something like this: `img/products/test.jpg`) which represents an img tag `src`.

When I am returning products objects from controller to view script I can easily generate images in .phtml file, img tag is generated this way:

```
echo '<img src="' . $this->basePath($product->src) . '">';
```

It normally works.
Now, I am modifying the same code to work with jQuery via AJAX request. So, I need to generate somehow img src in .js file.
`img/products/test.jpg` is easily generated in .js but what about the `$this->basePath()` part?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are expecting full url using `basePath()` view helper. This may not be something that you want. But if that is the case, then you have to configure to make the view helper work as you expected in the `module.config.php` as follows

```
'view_manager' => [ 

    'base_path' => 'http://yoursite.com/', // <-- replace with your website

    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],       
],
```

If you have this configured then you would get url including your domain name.

```
$this->basePath($product->src);
```

So the above would output

```
http://yoursite.com/img/products/test.jpg
```

There is another view helper that you can use for the same purpose which does not need configuration like the `basePath()`. And that is

```
$this->serverUrl(); // Outputs http://yoursite.com
```

But keep in mind that this view helper does not have a trailing slash `/`. So you need to put that manually as the following. Please note the `/` there.

```
$this->serverUrl('/path'); // Outputs http://yoursite.com/path
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is related to the view script `.phtml` for which I mentioned there wasn't any problem. My brain stopped working, I needed quick solution, so I asked question here. The answer is actually deadly simple. Equivalent of using `$this->basePath();` in `.phtml` files is simple using root relative links in `.js` files. So, you can generate `img src` like this: `<img class=\"pro\" src=\"/"+(this['src'])+"\">`.

Comment: Well, I described how you can output image source in a js script from within a view script. I am sorry that I did misunderstand. So I would tell now please write the right answer here that really worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.phtml files:

```
<img src="' . $this->basePath($product->src) . '">
```

.js files:

```
<img src=\"/"+this['src']+"\">
```